# ipython notebook boxplot not showing outliers on some computers

Tags: ipython, boxplot, seaborn

When doing boxplot in ipython notebook inline using seaborn, on one laptop (Windows 7), the plot will show outliers.  However, executing same code on my macbook and Windows 10 desktop, the outliers are not shown.  My code is:

```py
sns.set_context("talk", font_scale=1)

sns.boxplot(diff.pay_ratio, groupby=diff.status)
```

Comment: What versions of matplotlib and seaborn are on the two machines?

Answer (score 1):

This was discussed here as an issue with matplotlib using the edgewidth paramter:
https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/102

The fix that worked for me was to reset the faulty matplotlib parameters.

`matplotlib.rc("lines", markeredgewidth=0.5)`